# Cannot get html5 geolocation coordinates to work

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

I have tried examples here but just cannot get the html5 geolocation coordinates to work.
If I hardcode the coordinates it works fine.

```
  var infowindow;
  var map;

function initialize() {  

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(53.3452572,-6.2648937);

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), {
        center: latlng,
        zoom: 10,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,

    });

var request = {
location: latlng,

radius: 500000,

types: ['pet_shop','pet_store'] 
};
```

But if I try to use the following I get an error ReferenceError: position is not defined. What am I missing here or doing wrong?

```
 lat = position.coords.latitude;
     long = position.coords.longitude;
     var latlong = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
```

Comment: You are using geolocation api right ?

Comment: Where are you calling `getCurrentPosition`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either [watchPosition or getCurrentPosition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation) is supposed to be used to get the position in the callback. Here is a [similar example](https://jsfiddle.net/api/mdn/) from MDN page

```
function initialize() {  
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), {
          center: latlng,
          zoom: 10,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
          });
});
```

Comment: If you want to update location when user changes location, use watchPosition as well.